# GCal API: responseStatus "forces" invitee accept?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Our app is creating calendar events. Trying different combinations of parameters, it looks like when responseStatus is set = true for a given invitee (and that invitee is a GCal user) the accept of the event is "forced" -- ie, if I was the invitee the event just shows up on my calendar as accepted without me having acknowledged the invite in any way.

Can this possibly how things are supposed to work? On the face of it, it looks like I can use API to fill up peoples' calendars with events, causing them to get alerts, lose their free-time, etc.

FYI, in my settings for "Automatically add invitations to my calendar:" I have "No, only show invitations to which I have responded". My calendar is also shared with everyone in my company.

Comment: What happens if you don't set responseStatus to true? I think that property is responsible for setting the default response of the attendees to "accepted". Try setting it to false.

Comment: If I just omit responseStatus altogether I get a normal calendar workflow. The point of my question was this parameter -- in my environment at least -- **forces** the acceptance of invites on the invitee's calendar. For example, I create an event where you are an invitee, and set for you responseStatus=true. Then, when **you** look at your calendar you see the event as already accepted, even though you took no action.

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this question. Whenever I sign up for an event on something like youcanbook.me or cal.mixmax.com, the event gets added to my calendar instantly and shows that I've responded "I'm Going". How is it possible that with only my email address a third-party application can just add an event to my calendar AND confirm my attendance?

Comment: Update: I just tested this at https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert using the Try  this API. I gave it the calendarID of my own calendar, and included this in the request body:  "attendees": [{"email": "anotheremailaddress@gmail.com","responseStatus": "accepted"}]  and voilà! I added an event to that calendar and they showed up as accepting the invitation. I can echo the OPs concern that this could easily be used to spam user calendars. It's one thing if this is possible for calendars within an organization, but gmail addresses? That seems like a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `responseStatus` to `needsAction`.

Take a look at : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events and search for `responseStatus`.

Comment: I guess you missed the intent of my question ... I can have a normal calendar invite workflow just by not specifying anything for responseStatus. My issue is that by specifying responseStatus=true, this **forced** the meeting to be accepted **on the invitee's calendar** -- no need to send a replay accepting the invite! On the face of it I could fill other peoples' calendars with bogus accepted meetings, and that can't possibly be the intent of the API.